# Algorithm for determining number of discrete graphs in a dataset

Tags: algorithm, mapreduce, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a dataset that contains vertices and the other vertices that they are connected to.  This data set represents an undirected graph.  What I'm trying to determine is the number of discreet disconnected graphs that exist within the dataset.

For example the data below (vertex, array of connected vertices) would represent two discreet disconnected graphs:

```
123,[567,345]
345,[123,567,789]
567,[123,345]
789,[345]
321,[987]
987,[321]
```

On such a small data set it is pretty easy for me to envision ways for me to get to the answer, but as I scale this up to a data set with hundreds of millions of vertices I'm not sure I have anything that is very efficient.   I'm leaning toward doing something that can be run on Hadoop, but weather that is writing a MapReduce job directly or using something like Giraph or Faunus I'd love to get some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean the disconnected components of a graph. To do that, iteratively start BFSs  at unvisited vertices, keep a counter, increase it by one every time a new BFS starts, and mark the nodes of visited vertices with that counter. In the end you'll have both the number of connected components and a marking of the vertices partitioning them into those components.

Comment: check out Tarjan's algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bach said in the comments, this problem, **identifying connected components**, is typically solved by an ordinary breadth-first search. Skiena gives the basic algorithm as follows:

```
connected_components( graph *g ){
   int c, i; /* component number and counter */
   initialize_search( g );
   c = 0;
   for( i = 1; i <= g->num_vertices; i++ ){
      if( discovered[i] == FALSE ){
         c += 1;
         printf( "component %d: ", c );
         bfs( g, i );  // breadth first search
         printf( "\n" );
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work for "hundreds of millions of vertices" which for he asked.

Comment: @pkacprzak How could he calculate the connected components without at least looking at each edge once, given that he doesn't mention any preprocessing that's already happened? Linear time is the best he can do without prior knowledge.

Comment: @G.Bach of course that linear time is the best, I meant that he can't use the code above. How could he store the array of discovered in the memory?

Comment: @pkacprzak 100,000,000 * 8 bytes = 800 MB, it is a lot but if he can store the graph itself in memory, then he probably can spare another 800MB tops (8 bytes is pretty gracious, I'm not sure what language he is using and how much space an int array takes in the language of his choice). He would probably be better off with a database, though.

Comment: This is how you do it. Its not like there is some magical formula that allows you to solve large numbers of vertices easier than small numbers. If you have a memory problem you have to cache to disk and deal with it.

Comment: Of course, that's why he should lean towards a MapReduce rather than  a sequential algorithm